# How to Unregister Windows aero hotkeys?

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys, aero

Salve!  I just switched from WindowsXP to Windows7.  Now, I want to use the global hotkeys win+right, win+left, shift+win+right, etc., for something else, but find that they are already taken by Windows (I believe they are assigned globally to aero-snap or aero-something).

I tried adding the NoWinKeys entry in the registry, and so disabled the win+r command, but it didn't work for those other keys!

I also switched the theme to a normal, non-aero theme without any transparency, but that didn't help either.  I even used `Ultimate Windows Tweaker` to `Disable Aero Shake feature` and `Disable Aero Snap feature` and `Disable Aero Peek` too - but to no avail.

How can I disable those keys so I can assign them to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to intercept each Win+xxx command and reassign a different keystroke to it.  For example, you could have it recognize Win+Left as Ctrl+Win+Left, which you would then assign to the task you wanted the original Win+Left to accomplish.

Basic key intercepts and assignments like that are fairly simple.  For example, I use OneNote a lot, but I don't like some of the keystrokes it uses.  To open a Quick Note (which I don't use) is Win+N, but to open OneNote itself (which I do use) is Win+Shift+N.  The script to reassign Win+N to act as Win+Shift+N is as simple as this: `#n::Send #N`

Comment: Hey! That *does* work!  I already have a hotkey script running - I just didn't realize that autohotkey would override them.  Thanks!  For an example, I did: #right::
msgbox, Hey bob!
return

Comment: Wow, I really thought it was not possible at all...

Comment: This works like a charm, actually!  No problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-i-change-the-windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts/0110d32d-66c0-4ce7-8682-eeb896e80c3f) post on Microsoft forums, you cannot De-register and reassign the shortcut keys associated with the Win key.

Comment: That is horrendous! Surely there is a hack?

Comment: None that I'm aware of..

Answer (score 0):

Look at here: [How to disable the keyboard Windows key?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150305132330/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/216893)

It has a [Microsoft Fix it](https://www.bing.com/?ref=go&linkid=9738719) link to *disable* window key, and [another link](https://www.bing.com/?ref=go&linkid=9738718) to *enable* window key.

just download the setup and follow the instructions.

Comment: Please, I don't want to disable the actual `keys` - I want to use the `hotkeys` for another application.